# Functional limits and definition of continuity - difference and implications?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, definition

Continuity:

A function $f : A → \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at a point $c ∈ A$ if, for
all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $δ > 0$ such that whenever $|x − c| < δ$ (and $x ∈ A$) it
follows that $|f(x) − f(c)| < \epsilon$

Functional Limits:

Let $f : A → \mathbb{R}$, and let $c$ be a limit point of the domain $A$.
We say that $\lim_{x→c} f(x) = L$ provided that, for all $\epsilon  > 0$, there exists a $δ > 0$ such that whenever $0 < |x − c| < δ$ (and $x ∈ A$) it follows that $|f(x) − L| < \epsilon$.

I see two differences in these definitions - firstly, for continuity, $x=c$ is a possibility and secondly, that $c \in A$, the limit point $c$ must be contained in the set for continuity.

My question is, when do we need to use this, and what are the implications of these results?

Answer (score 1):

For the existence of the limit $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ the function $f$ needs not be defined at $x=c$, or if it is defined, the value $f(c)$ may have no relation to the value of the limit.

For $f$ to be continuous at $c$, $f$ must be defined at $x=c$, the limit  $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ must exist, and its value must be equal to $f(c)$.